# Ignore the first space in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Time              Latitude Longitude
2021-09-12 23:13    44.63     -63.56
2021-09-14 23:13    43.78     -62
2021-09-16 23:14    44.83     -54.6
```

`2021-09-12 23:13` is under `Time` column.

I would like to open it using pandas. But there is a problem with the first column. It contains a space. If I open it using:

```
import pandas as pd
points = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
```

I get

|  | Time | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-12 | 23:13 | 44.630 | -63.560 |
| 2021-09-14 | 23:13 | 43.780 | -62.000 |
| 2021-09-16 | 23:14 | 44.830 | -54.600 |

But I would like to skip the space in the first column in CSV (`2021-09-12 23:13` should be under `Time` column) like:

|  | Time | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-09-12 23:13 | 44.630 | -63.560 |
| 1 | 2021-09-14 23:13 | 43.780 | -62.000 |
| 2 | 2021-09-16 23:14 | 44.830 | -54.600 |

How can I ignore the first space when using `pd.read_csv`?

Please do not stick to this csv file. This is a general question to skip (not to consider as a delimiter) the first space(s) in the first column. Because everyone knows that the first space is part of the time value, not a delimiter.

Comment: Are the columns separated by spaces or tabs? If the separator is a tab, then instead of `delim_whitespace=True`, you could use `sep=\t`. Spaces in column values then wouldn't matter.

Comment: All are spaces.

Comment: For such a character-sensitive problem, please include the raw text of your delimited file. The Markdown table is pretty but hides really relevant information for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be parsing the first two parts as a datetime. By using a space as a delimiter, it would imply the header has three columns. The space after the date though is being seen as an extra column.

A workaround is to skip the header entirely and supply your own column names. The `parse_dates` parameter can be used to tell Pandas to parse the first two columns as a single combined datetime object.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

points = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=" ", 
    skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, index_col=None, 
    parse_dates=[[0, 1]], names=["Date", "Time", "Latitude", "Longitude"])

print(points)
```

Should give you the following dataframe:

```
            Date_Time  Latitude  Longitude
0 2021-09-12 23:13:00     44.63     -63.56
1 2021-09-14 23:13:00     43.78     -62.00
2 2021-09-16 23:14:00     44.83     -54.60
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have shown is not a csv file. Full stop. Pandas `read_csv` is indeed versatile enough to possibly find workaround allowing to process it. But it is actually a fixed width fields file and should be read with `pd.read_fwf`:

```
pd.read_fwf(file_name, [(0,16), (16,26), (26, 40)])
```

directly gives:

```
               Time  Latitude  Longitude
0  2021-09-12 23:13     44.63     -63.56
1  2021-09-14 23:13     43.78     -62.00
2  2021-09-16 23:14     44.83     -54.60
```

---

From your edit, you only want to tell `read_csv` to consider the first white space as a non delimiter character. I know no simple way to do that. The hard way is to read the file, replace the first space in each and every line with a different character. Then you submit that changed file to `read_csv` with a custom converter for the first column to change the special character back to a space:

```
with open('test.csv') as fdin, open('test2.csv', 'w') as fdout):
    fdout.write(next(fdin)    # do not process the header line
    for line in fdin:
        fdout.write(line.replace(' ', '_', 1)

df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', delim_whitespace=True,
                 converters = {'Time': lambda x: x.replace('_', ' ')})
```

It gives too:

```
               Time  Latitude  Longitude
0  2021-09-12 23:13     44.63     -63.56
1  2021-09-14 23:13     43.78     -62.00
2  2021-09-16 23:14     44.83     -54.60
```

Comment: Please do not stick to the csv in the question. What if the spaces between them were different. For example; `Time       Latitude            Longitude` and `2021-09-12 23:13       44.63   -63.56`, I just want pandas not to consider the first space as a delimiter.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz: I know no easy way for that. For the hard way, please see my edit...

Answer (score 2):

Try to fix the column and the index after load the file:

```
import pandas as pd

points = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delim_whitespace=True)

points = points.assign(Time=pd.to_datetime(df.index + ' ' + df['Time'])) \
               .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> points
                 Time  Latitude  Longitude
0 2021-09-12 23:13:00     44.63     -63.56
1 2021-09-14 23:13:00     43.78     -62.00
2 2021-09-16 23:14:00     44.83     -54.60
```

Comment: not working, same result.

Comment: Maybe you closed too fast if it does not working

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz. I tried another solution, can you check it please?

Comment: I would like to ignore in `pd.read_csv`. I know how to edit after loading csv.

Comment: I don't think it's possible if it looks like a delimiter.

Comment: I want to say "Hey pandas. The first space(s) are not a delimiter. Don't consider them as a delimiter".

Comment: No you can't sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is in 2 different kind of formats:

- your headerrow has a single space between `'Latitude'` and `'Longitude'`.
- the "data" rows look to be separated by multiple spaces.

You can either edit your data and add a second space between lat & long or trick it by supplying the column headers separately:

Create file:

```
with open("test.csv","w") as f:
    f.write("""Time              Latitude Longitude
2021-09-12 23:13    44.63     -63.56
2021-09-14 23:13    43.78     -62
2021-09-16 23:14    44.83     -54.6""")
```

Parse file:

```
import pandas as pd

# ignore files headers, supply own, use multiple spaces as seperator
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter = "   ", 
                 header=0, names = ["Time","Latitude","Longitude"])

print (df)
```

Output:

```
               Time  Latitude  Longitude
0  2021-09-12 23:13     44.63     -63.56
1  2021-09-14 23:13     43.78     -62.00
2  2021-09-16 23:14     44.83     -54.60
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `pd.read_csv(..., skipinitialspace=True)`[^1](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)?

> skipinitialspacebool, default False
>
> Skip spaces after delimiter.

The Python **csv** module also has a skip-initial-space option[^2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) (not sure if Pandas made up its own, or wraps this):

> Dialect.skipinitialspace
>
> When True, whitespace immediately following the delimiter is ignored. The default is False.

Even though it explicitly states "following the delimiter", it does the sensible thing and ignores leading whitespace in *any column/cell*.

Given the following **input.csv**, which has a leading space in all of columns 1 and 2:

```
 H1  H2
 A  1
 B  2
 C  3
```

When I run this:

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

I get:

```py
['H1', 'H2']
['A', '1']
['B', '2']
['C', '3']
```

Even if Pandas doesn't support this, at least you could use this as a preliminary transform and feed into Pandas.